# Rspec is giving an error with my layout links from the rails tutorial: “Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace”

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Same question, but solution did not work:, I've tried several versions of rspec:
[Why is Rspec saying "Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517724/rspec-is-giving-an-error-with-my-layout-links-from-the-rails-tutorial-failure-e)

```
dpalacio:sample_app dpalacio$ rspec -v
2.0.0.beta.18
dpalacio:sample_app dpalacio$ rspec spec/
controllers/    factories.rb    models/         requests/       spec_helper.rb  
dpalacio:sample_app dpalacio$ rspec spec/requests/
FFFFF

Finished in 0.55501 seconds
5 examples, 5 failures

1) LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

2) LayoutLinks should have a Contact page at '/contact'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

3) LayoutLinks should have an About page at '/about'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

4) LayoutLinks should have a Help page at '/help'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

5) LayoutLinks should have a Help page at '/signup'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185
```

And the same with the 2.0.1 version:

```
dpalacio:sample_app dpalacio$ rspec -v
2.0.1
dpalacio:sample_app dpalacio$ rspec spec/
controllers/    factories.rb    models/         requests/       spec_helper.rb  
dpalacio:sample_app dpalacio$ rspec spec/requests/
FFFFF

Finished in 0.55501 seconds
5 examples, 5 failures

1) LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

2) LayoutLinks should have a Contact page at '/contact'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

3) LayoutLinks should have an About page at '/about'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

4) LayoutLinks should have a Help page at '/help'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185

5) LayoutLinks should have a Help page at '/signup'
    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
    stack level too deep
    # /Users/dpalacio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb:185
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the issue, the issue is not RSPEC but WEBRAT.
Add to your Gemfile:

**gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'**

The version of RSPEC should be:
gem 'rspec', '2.0.1'

Comment: This worked for me. I Originally saw this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517724/rspec-is-giving-an-error-with-my-layout-links-from-the-rails-tutorial-failure-e which took me in the rspec direction. But it is indeed a webrat issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see this as a (purely) webrat issue ...

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.18'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'launchy'
end

... since I'm using capybara instead of webrat.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Having the same problem here.

Comment: I got the same error after updating to grape-entity 0.4.0. With version 0.3.0 everything works.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be an issue as of **rspec 2.2.0**