# Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails (3.0) Tutorial Lesson 3 Slightly Dynamic Pages (Home) Should have the right title Test Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

new to ROR and working through the MH tutorials. I am working through lesson 03 and have slightly dynamic pages configuration double and triple checked for home page title and get the following error message when I save page_controller_spec.rb or home.html.erb.

**Error Message**

Failures:

1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title",:content =>  "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample | Home")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_selector?' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007f99bad28e48>
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in`block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 0.1075 seconds
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:11 # PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title

any direction would be appreciated

All the best Peter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors with Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial Chapter 7 - Specifically Rspec Testing Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007492/errors-with-michael-hartls-rails-tutorial-chapter-7-specifically-rspec-testin)

Comment: You might want to checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388638/broken-controller-tests-after-installing-capybara

Answer (score 0):

I googled your problem and found this:

http://getsatisfaction.com/railstutorial/topics/rspec_undefined_method_has_selector

Looks like you're missing a needed gem which is what implements `has_selector?` for you.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be called `have_tag`, but RSpec now uses `Webrat` for `have_selector`. Install that.

http://www.rubyfocus.biz/blog/2011/01/08/from_have_tag_to_have_selector_in_rspec2_gotchas.html

Comment: Thank you for everyones input. I am now working through the Rails for Zombies 1 - 2 tutorials from Codeschool which I think are better for newbees like myself. I will then move through the latest Michael Hartl's tutorial once I have more knowledge. The journey is long but exciting. Thanks again