# RSpec error while following http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've searched everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution. I have been following the tutorial on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and I'm on Chapter 3 trying to execute a test using "rspec spec/"

However I keep recieving the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant ActionController::TestCase::Assertions
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-expectations-2.5.0/lib/rspec/expectations/backward_compatibility.rb:6:in `const_missing'
 # /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/integration.rb:18
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webrat-0.7.1/lib/webrat/integrations/rails.rb:2
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webrat-0.7.1/lib/webrat/core/configuration.rb:105:in `mode='
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-rails-2.5.0/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:172
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webrat-0.7.1/lib/webrat/core/configuration.rb:9:in `configure'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-rails-2.5.0/lib/rspec/rails/example/controller_example_group.rb:172
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:29:in `run_in'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:64:in `run_all'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:64:in `each'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:64:in `run_all'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:110:in `run_hook'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:191:in `eval_before_eachs'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:191:in `each'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:191:in `eval_before_eachs'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:144:in `run_before_each'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:48:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:106:in `with_around_hooks'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:46:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:99:in `with_pending_capture'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:98:in `catch'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:98:in `with_pending_capture'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:45:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:262:in `run_examples'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:258:in `map'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:258:in `run_examples'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:232:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:233:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:233:in `map'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:233:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in `map'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:12:in `report'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rspec:19
```

I've attempted to uninstall and reinstall gems with no luck.

Here is my gem list:

```
    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
actionpack (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
activemodel (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.3.2, 1.3.1)
activeresource (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
activesupport (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
arel (2.0.8, 2.0.7)
autotest (4.4.6)
autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.10)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemon_controller (0.2.6, 0.2.5)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
file-tail (1.0.5)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.15, 2.2.14)
mime-types (1.16)
nifty-generators (0.4.5, 0.4.4)
nokogiri (1.4.4)
passenger (3.0.2)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
railties (3.0.4, 3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7)
redgreen (1.2.2)
rspec (2.3.0)
rspec-core (2.3.1)
rspec-expectations (2.3.0)
rspec-mocks (2.3.0)
rspec-rails (2.3.0)
ruby-oci8 (2.0.4)
spruz (0.2.5)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
sys-uname (0.8.5)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.24)
webrat (0.7.3, 0.7.1)
ZenTest (4.4.2)
```

Gem File

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.5.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end
```

Comment: What is your gemfile looks like?

Comment: This answer suggests changing webrat to 0.7.1 only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517724/why-is-rspec-saying-failure-error-unable-to-find-matching-line-from-backtrace/4139573#4139573 (and then re-run 'bundle install') Does that help?

Comment: I included the gem file in the original post, webrat 0.7.1 didnt seem to change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to upgrade rspec to 2.5.0
You should have then:
rspec (2.5.0)
rspec-core (2.5.1)
rspec-expectations (2.5.0)
rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.5.0)

And remove webrat 0.7.1, just keep 0.7.3
webrat (0.7.3)

Comment: I originally was using 2.5.0 and 0.7.1 of webrat and went back to a old version to test. But I updated again and still not having any luck

Comment: @keystone - interesting, as I was going through this chapter few days ago and everything worked ok with 2.5.0 and 0.7.1. I will have a look later at my configuration again and let you know

Comment: Thanks, Just FYI I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and Aptana RadRails. Although I don't believe Aptana would make a difference.

Comment: @keystone - Hmmm. I didn't manage to replicate your error. First I've tried to get setup identical to yours, i.e ubuntu 10.10, ruby1.9.2, rubygems 1.3.7, rails 3.0.4, rspec 2.5.0, webrat 0.7.3. I went through chapter3 line by line and rspec spec/ worked. Then I've noticed that you are using ruby 1.8.*. I thought maybe it's a case and I switched to ruby1.8.7-p160 (with RVM it's a breeze). But again I had no problem to run rspec. I would suggest to get RVM and try with different ruby builds, rubygems etc.

Comment: damn! well thanks for all the effort you've put in. I have no experience with RVM but looks like I have plans for tomorrow haha

Comment: fresh install fixed whatever problem I was having, thanks for all the help Liutauras!

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar solution to m.galkiewicz. 
I am on ubuntu 10.10. I identified this issue because of the following line from your error:
 # /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/integration.rb:18

When I compared to my friends working install on the same version of ubuntu, action_controller was not within the /usr/lib/ruby/1.8 path.

I found that I had installed rails and rake via apt-get, not via rubygems.  Here are the modifications I made to get it going:

1. sudo apt-get remove rails
2. sudo gem install rails
3. sudo bundle install

I was then able to run rspec and continue with the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working by removing rails from apt-get (as previously recommended by others) and installing from rubygems, but that was not enough.  It was necessary to then run 'apt-get autoremove'.  Now all is well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going through this book too and am documenting how it's going [www.ridingrails.co.uk](http://www.ridingrails.co.uk) might help.
My Gemfile looks like

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'spork', '0.9.0.rc8'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '0.1.0'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'annotate'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

but took me a bit of time to get everything up and running.  I'd take a look at the book use the gems that are there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on debian squeeze. Make sure that rails and other ruby related packages are installed from rubygems and not your distro's repository.

ii  libruby                                  4.5
ii  libruby1.8                               1.8.7.302-2
ii  libruby1.9.1                             1.9.2.0-2
ii  libxml-ruby1.8                           1.1.3-2 
ii  libxslt-ruby                             0.9.2-5 
ii  libxslt-ruby1.8                          0.9.2-5 
ii  ruby                                     4.5
ii  ruby-dev                                 4.5
ii  ruby1.8                                  1.8.7.302-2 
ii  ruby1.8-dev                              1.8.7.302-2 
ii  ruby1.9.1                                1.9.2.0-2
ii  rubygems                                 1.3.7-3
ii  rubygems1.8                              1.3.7-3

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem.
We looked at the backtrace, which was:

```
  16) DesktopsController DELETE destroy redirects to the desktops list
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant ActionController::TestCase::Assertions
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-expectations-2.5.0/lib/rspec/expectations/backward_compatibility.rb:6:in `const_missing'
 # /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/action_controller/integration.rb:18
 # /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/webrat-0.7.3/lib/webrat/integrations/rails.rb:2
```

noticing that this was requiring dpkg'ed rails from webrat, we looked at integration/rails.rb. We see that it was including action_controller/integration.rb.
Looking at our action_controller 3.0.4, we see that this does not exist anymore.
Of course, removing the dpkg installed ones may change this problem, but really it is an API incompatibility between webrat 0.7.3 and action_controller 3.0.4.
I do not see a newer version of webrat, so we will live with this manual patch, since we need it only for testing, not in production.